# How to set a timeout to "connect()" function on C sockets?

Tags: c++, sockets

I have to connect a several ips on same subnet concurrently.
Buy its takes me too long! (almost 25 seconds) to wait untill the all "`connect()`" functions done!

How can I oprtimize this behavior in winsock, CPP?
I find about somthing called "`select`" but aperrently it works only for linux so..

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141(VS.85).aspx MS-Windows has some variation of `select()`. You need to RTFM.

Comment: select is available on Windows, but it doesn't work in quite the same way it does on POSIX systems. And you need to ask a better question.

Comment: libevent is a good library which can be used in Linux and windows as well, asynchronous operation are really good and clean . For C++   you can consider boost asio

Answer (score 1):

`select()` works on Unix, Linux, Windows, Netware, and every other platform I have ever tested it on.

1. Put the socket into non-blocking mode.
2. Call `connect()`. It will fail with EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK or EINPROGRESS.
3. Call `select()` with your desired timeout, with the socket set into the `writefds`, i.e. select for writeability.
4. When the socket becomes writeable, it is connected. If that doesn't happen within your timeout period, close it, otherwise reset it to blocking mode if you prefer and proceed.